# mdadm.conf file needed? How to create and where?

Tags: raid, mdadm, mirrors

I'm running ubuntu mate 18.04.  My system is on an nvme.  I had a 4TB HD with all my back ups along with my plex media.  I got a second identical HD for Christmas and used it to create a raid1 array with missing (the original HD), then copied the data from orig. HD to the raid, then added the orig.HD  to the raid and it is building/repairing the raid currently.

I used the DISKS GUI to mark the array for auto mount.. that created an entry if fstab.  The only thing I can think of I am unsure about is the mdadm.conf file.  The many guides I have read show creating it using:  `mdadm --detail --scan --verbose >> /etc/mdadm.conf`. When the program was installed it created its own mdadm.conf file as `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` but all I see in it are comment lines.

A few examples I have read show creating the file in the mdadm directory but most show creating it in etc not the mdadm sub-directory.  That's the history.. my questions... I assume the file is needed (even though I think the array would mount on reboot) in case it ever needs to repair.  Do I create it using the `"mdadm --detail --scan --verbose >> /etc/mdadm.conf"` command?  Does it matter if the file is in etc or the sub-directory of mdadm?  Should I remove or rename the existing mdadm.conf file to prevent conflicts?  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: This may be a slight variation from the normal Linux setup on Ubuntu so I would suggest you use that subfolder. See here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/mdadm.conf.5.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The little I know it appears that Ubuntu is different when it comes to where the `mdadm` file is placed. I have also seen the `/etc/` location suggested in Linux Foundation documentations but when running on Ubuntu I discovered that it has it's own stored in the location `/etc/mdadm` subfolder.

So I would suggest you use that location and seen in this [document](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/mdadm.conf.5.html), where Ubuntu location is different. The command would be

```
sudo mdadm --detail --scan --verbose | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Comment: This was a clear answer to my question.  Thank you.  When I ran the command as sudo it came up with a permissions error.  During my research I had watched the "031 Creating a RAID 1 array with mdadm" on youtube by Sistem Odasi which addressed this problem.  I did a chmod 777 on the mdadm.conf file and afterwards this command worked.

Comment: @DSongwriter, you shouldn't `chmod` the file. The reason the command fails is that it's trying to write to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`, which is owned by `root` and now writable by you. `>>` creates a new shell that tries to append piped data as the current user, regardless of who ran the command whose output is being piped (`sudo`, i.e. `root`). One correct way to append output to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` is `sudo mdadm --detail --scan --verbose | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`

Comment: Edited the command to use `tee -a` instead of `>>`.  Yeah, please don't chmod your conf file :)  Or well, chmod it back to what it was before if you haven't already.